# Specify superClass options when it's combined grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I think the title explains my question well, in antlr grammar options, there is a superClass option to specify the superclass of the grammar. But it will only edit the Parser's class(java)'s superclass on combined grammar.

Is there any possible way to make it edit the Lexer class's superclass, or do I need to separate the grammar file?

```
grammar InterPython;

@header {
package org.interpython.antlr;

import org.interpython.antlr.parsing.LexerBase;
}

options{
superClass = 'LexerBase';
}
```

And this throws a lot of errors because this make a Parser extend a Lexer

Comment: Sorry grammar error this *makes* a Parser *extends* a Lexer

Answer (score 1):

> or do I need to separate the grammar file?

Yes, create separate lexer- and parser grammars:

#### InterPythonParser.g4

```
parser grammar InterPythonParser;

options {
superClass = ParserBase;
tokenVocab = InterPythonLexer;
}

...
```

#### InterPythonLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar InterPythonLexer;

options {
superClass = LexerBase;
}

...
```

Note that you don't need quotes around LexerBase: `superClass = LexerBase`